# Ratio and the equality of money

Tags: ratio

Bernice and Lily have some money. If Bernice gives Lily \$120, they   will have an equal amount of money. If Lily gives Bernice \$120, the ratio of the amount of Bernice's money to the amount of Lily's money will become 4:1. How much money does each of them have?

Comment: Bernice and Lily have some money. If Bernice gives Lily 120,they will have an equal amount of money. If Lily gives Bernice $120, the ratio of the amount of Bernice's money to the amount of Lily's money will become 4:1. How much money does each of them have?

Comment: You have two linear equations in the variables „money of Bernice“ and „money of Lily“

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ is the money Bernice has. $y$ the other's.

First sentence :
We have $$x-120=y+120$$
Second sentence :
$$\frac{x+120}{y-120}=4$$
or
$$x+120=4\left(y-120\right)$$

Two equations ,two unknowns.
Substract the last equation to the first one : 
$$240=4\left(y-120\right)-y-120$$
Thus,
$$y=280$$
$$x=520$$